# Laravel 5.1 - How to access dynamic URI segment in Controller and Route

Tags: php, request, uri, laravel-5.1, segment

Team,

I am using Laravel 5.1, In which I have to use URI segment feature same as Codeigniter

Like eg.
URL - `www.example.com/user_id/user_type/user_role/....`

Want to access those parameters `user_id`, `user_type`, `user_role` in controller and also want to manage the Route file.

Can anyone guide me how to do this in LARAVEL?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Pleas read the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.1

Answer (score 0):

In your routes.php file:

```
Route::get('user/{user_id}/{user_type}/{user_role}', ['uses' => 'UserController@index', 'as' => 'user.index']);
```

In your UserController.php file:

```
public function index($user_id, $user_type, $user_role) {
  dd($user_id, $user_type, $user_role);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, But I need the dynamic solution, Where we can send as many variable in link irrespective of route change.

Answer (score 0):

In your route.php file write this - 
   If you have any optional parameter then put a Question mark(?) after that, I assumed that the parameter user_role is optional.

```
 Route::get('user/{user_id}/{user_type}/{user_role?}', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@getIndex',
    'as' => 'user.get.index' // You can write any unique name you want, This will be your route name.
 ]);
```

In your Controller, You can access these parameters like this -

```
 public function getIndex($user_id, $user_type, $user_role) {
    // Here your parameters will be available to use.
   //  Write your logic
 }
```